# Verilog inital value for flip flop

Tags: verilog, flipflop, waveform

I am trying to write verilog code that will set the initial value of the output of a positive-edge triggered flip-flop to 0. The behaviour of the flip-flop circuit is exactly what I want AFTER the clock or the input c hits. Unfortunately, at the very beginning (before any activity in c or clk) the x value is wrong because my initial statement seems to have no effect:

[image: Waveform Simulation]
[image: Constructed Quartus Circuit]

I understand that the problem may be that the Q output of the flipflop is always initially 0, and the inverter sets the x value to 1. Therefore, could someone suggest how to change the code so that the **initial value of x is 0**? Maybe use a series of latches? Essentially, the behaviour I want is that when the c value is high, x is also high, but when the clock hits, x is always reset to 0.

```
module test (c, x, clk);
   input c;
   input clk;
   output x;
   reg x;
   initial begin
     x = 0;
   end
   always @(posedge clk or posedge c) begin
      if (c) begin
        x = c;
      end else begin
        x = 1'b0;
      end
   end
endmodule
```

Comment: x is a really bad choice for a verilog variable. As `x` has a special meaning of an unknown value.

Comment: Have you tried to put x=1 in your initial statement, so that when it is inverted it becomes 0?

Answer (score 1):

You are using `c` as an active high reset, then setting the value to `c` rather than  1'b0. It is active high so `c` is always 1 when this code executes. The solution to this is the reset condition to 0 not c:

```
always @(posedge clk or posedge c) begin
  if (c) begin
    x <= 1'b0; //Reset Condition
  end else begin
    //x <= ...;
  end
end
```

Your code makes use of an `initial` and asynchronous reset. This does not really represent any type of hardware you have to choose one or the other, you can not have both.

The waveform in the question does not show the async reset being applied at the start of the simulation. you should apply it for at least 1 clock cycle and release it on the posedge of your clock.

Comment: It should with non-blocking assignments

Comment: This does not resolve my problem. When I do a timing simulation, x is still HIGH.

Comment: @Julia it is still high while reset (c) is applied? Your wave form shown in the quaetsion does not apply reset (c) at the start of simulation.

Comment: If c will be high, then x will be high. Unfortunately I want x to be 0 in the initial state, but Quartus constructs what it thinks to be the optimal version as that little flip-flop component, and ignores my initial declaration.

Comment: @Julia I have expanded answer a little.

Answer (score 0):

(Answering after 5 years; might get useful to someone like me.)

The schematic output from Vivado 2020.2 gives this schematic. So the problem seems to be according to schematic in question. Although the two schematics are functionally same, the functioning before inputs are applied isn't same.

[image: Schematic output from Vivado 2020.2]

Somehow, the Quartus (used in question) needs to be forced to utilize `PRE` instead of `CLRN` input for `c`. Accordingly, the following Code should work as desired in question with all simulators.

```vhdl
module test (input c, x, output reg clk);
   initial x = 0;
   always @(posedge clk or posedge c)
      if (c) x = 1'b1;
      else x = 1'b0;
endmodule
```

Comment: It is a little unclear whether you are talking about Quartus or Vivado here. Also, you start talking about **synthesis** and then say your approach "might work...with all **simulators**". If you really are talking about synthesis then the target implementation becomes relevant. Designing a flip-flop that assume a known state **as power is coming up** is very difficult, so assuming an unknown output at t=0 seems prudent.

Comment: Hey Elliot, thank you for pointing out. Do the edits resolve it?

Meanwhile, "might" because I haven't used many simulators. Vivado, ISE I can predict the output schematic. Quartus, ModelSim etc, not sure (now after seeing the question).